# Samsung 860 evo slow speeds

Tags: windows-10, ssd

Recently i bought a samsung 860 evo 250gb ssd and slapped it into my laptop internal sata 3 port everything is working fine except for the speeds. Sequential reads are fine even sequential write are okish but what bothers me the most is the 4k random read/write those are really slow when compared to other people’s SSDs should i be worried or is it normal? AHCI is enabled trim is enabled rapid is disabled and write caching is enabled

Photos
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vAS8EHtnhVrX6FPEj0baKa4HuO7P28dt/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H-YfUQtrtw7DAe6i-K__EZovxT7XOOMn/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please provide OS details,  any details on a plausible cause and remedy depend heavily on that info.

Comment: Windows 10 of course you can also see in the photo

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) (not drive.google.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.